# How to send command line input responses in Django tests

Tags: django, testing

I have a Django management command that will ask for command line input (y/n) and I'm now writing a test for this.

Currently when I run the test (as is now), the test will stop and wait for the y/n input. But how can I write/update my test so that I can send a y/n response to the call_command function?

For info, my management command code is (imports removed - but full code at: https://github.com/DigitalCampus/django-oppia/blob/master/oppia/management/commands/remove_duplicate_trackers.py):

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = _(u"Removes any duplicate trackers based on UUID")

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """
        Remove page/media/quiz trackers with no UUID
        """
        result = Tracker.objects.filter(Q(type='page')
                                        | Q(type='quiz')
                                        | Q(type='media'),
                                        uuid=None).delete()
        print(_(u"\n\n%d trackers removed that had no UUID\n" % result[0]))

        """
        Remove proper duplicate trackers - using min id
        """
        trackers = Tracker.objects.filter(Q(type='page')
                                          | Q(type='quiz')
                                          | Q(type='media')) \
            .values('uuid') \
            .annotate(dcount=Count('uuid')) \
            .filter(dcount__gte=2)

        for index, tracker in enumerate(trackers):
            print("%d/%d" % (index, trackers.count()))
            exclude = Tracker.objects.filter(uuid=tracker['uuid']) \
                .aggregate(min_id=Min('id'))
            deleted = Tracker.objects.filter(uuid=tracker['uuid']) \
                .exclude(id=exclude['min_id']).delete()
            print(_(u"%d duplicate tracker(s) removed for UUID %s based on \
                   min id" % (deleted[0], tracker['uuid'])))

        """
        Remember to run summary cron from start
        """
        if result[0] + trackers.count() > 0:
            print(_(u"Since duplicates have been found and removed, you \
                    should now run `update_summaries` to ensure the \
                    dashboard graphs are accurate."))
            accept = input(_(u"Would you like to run `update_summaries` \
                                now? [Yes/No]"))
            if accept == 'y':
                call_command('update_summaries', fromstart=True)
```

and my test code is:

```
def test_remove_with_duplicates(self):
    Tracker.objects.create(
        user_id=1,
        course_id = 1,
        type = "page",
        completed = True,
        time_taken = 280,
        activity_title = "{\"en\": \"Calculating the uptake of antenatal care services\"}",
        section_title = "{\"en\": \"Planning Antenatal Care\"}",
        uuid = "835713f3-b85e-4960-9cdf-128f04014178")
    out = StringIO()
    tracker_count_start = Tracker.objects.all().count()

    call_command('remove_duplicate_trackers', stdout=out)

    tracker_count_end = Tracker.objects.all().count()
    self.assertEqual(tracker_count_start-1, tracker_count_end)
```

Any help much appreciated, and if you need any extra info/code, just let me know, thanks.

**Edit**
I tried the suggestion from @xyres to add 'interactive=False' but I got a type error with this:

```
TypeError: Unknown option(s) for remove_duplicate_trackers command: interactive. Valid options are: force_color, help, no_color, pythonpath, settings, skip_checks, stderr, stdout, traceback, verbosity, version
```

I then also tried with 'skip_checks=True' but this still made the test hang awaiting on command line input

Comment: Can you try passing `interactive=False` argument to `call_command` and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @xyres - I just tried this but got: TypeError: Unknown option(s) for remove_duplicate_trackers command: interactive. Valid options are: force_color, help, no_color, pythonpath, settings, skip_checks, stderr, stdout, traceback, verbosity, version

Comment: Don't have time to write up a full answer right now, but have you considered [mocking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) the `input` method?

Comment: Just a few seconds late, but I would recommend the same as @RishiG, as with mocking you can simulate the desired input with code. Just make a mock that returns 'y'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use [`mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) for this sort of thing.  Here's a pared-down example loosely based on your command.  First, the management command which just prompts for and accepts a single line of input

```py
from django.core.management import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        accept = input("Would you like to run `update_summaries` now? [Yes/No]")
        if accept == 'y':
            self.stdout.write("Updating Summaries!")
            return
        self.stdout.write("Not updating Summaries...")
```

Next, here is the `TestCase`.  I like to use a call wrapper to consolidate the logic for patching and allow testing different options etc.

```py
from io import StringIO

from unittest import mock

from django.core.management import call_command

from django.test import TestCase


class UpdateTestCase(TestCase):

    @mock.patch("my_app.management.commands.update.input")
    def _call_wrapper(self, response_value, mock_input=None):
        def input_response(message):
            return response_value
        mock_input.side_effect = input_response
        out = StringIO()
        call_command('update', stdout=out)
        return out.getvalue().rstrip()

    def test_yes(self):
        """Test update command with "y" response
        """
        self.assertEqual("Updating Summaries!", self._call_wrapper('y'))

    def test_no(self):
        """Test update command with "n" response
        """
        self.assertEqual("Not updating Summaries...", self._call_wrapper('n'))
```

Comment: just what I needed! I made a minor update in your sample code for the "import mock" - I'm on django 2.2 and python 3.6 if that makes any difference for the imports

Comment: cool.  I'm working in a python project that was upgraded from 2.7, so there is a requirement on the `mock` module and it's imported directly.  Good edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the answer above gives an example that's too DRY. I like to separate the setup phase from running the code. You don't need to create a separate wrapper or use `side_effect`. After all, `input` is just a function.

My take is that for such command

```py
from django.core.management import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        accept = input("Would you like to run `update_summaries` now? [Yes/No]")
        if accept == 'y':
            self.stdout.write("Updating Summaries!")
            return
        self.stdout.write("Not updating Summaries...")
```

you could write

```py
from django.test.utils import captured_stdout
from unittest import mock

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.test import TestCase


class UpdateTestCase(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("my_app.management.commands.update.input", return_value="y")
    def test_yes(self, m):
        with captured_stdout() as stdout:
            call_command("update")
            output = stdout.getvalue()
        self.assertEqual("Updating Summaries!", output)

    @mock.patch("my_app.management.commands.update.input", return_value="n")
    def test_no(self, m):
        with captured_stdout() as stdout:
            call_command("update")
            output = stdout.getvalue()
        self.assertEqual("Not updating Summaries...", output)
```